# Python NLTK ngram code does not give results

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, cluster-analysis, corpus

I am working on Sindhi, a non english corpus analysis using NLTK tool in python. I imported all the concerned liberaries in python and processed code for loading zipped file. The code for zipped file is working fine and load the data. The code is as below:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('D:\Sindhicorpus.zip') as z:
    print (len(z.namelist()))
    for filename in z.namelist():
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            # read the file
            with z.open(filename, 'rU') as rf:
                line = rf.readline().decode('utf8') 
               # print(line)
```

After this I process code for generating ngrams but that code does not shows results without any error. The code is as below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
line = ""
for val in filename:
    line += val
tokens = line.split()
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
print(finder.nbest(bigram_measures.pmi, 100))
```

This code just show brackets like [ ]

After this code, I processed an other code but it is also not showing the results without showing any error. The code is as below:

```
from nltk import ngrams
n = 2
sixgrams = ngrams(filename.split(), n)
for grams in sixgrams:
  print(grams)
```

Please help me in resolving my problem

Mazhar

Comment: For the second example: `nltk.ngrams(x, n)` is an empty iterator if `len(x) < n`. Since your filename probably contains no spaces, `filename.split()` yields a list with one element, which is shorter than 2 (which you assigned to `n`).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reading the files.

Instead, you concatenate the file names, and try to parse that.

```
for val in filename:
    line += val
```

You need to fix this.

Comment: I need solution

Comment: You have all you need, you just need to get your variables right.